# PHP create image from base64 data corrupted

Tags: javascript, php, base64

a base64-encoded image-data string is posted from frontend through ajax request:

```
var req = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: 'data=' + data, // data=iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...
};
$http(req).then(...);
```

The destination is a php script:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
file_put_contents("tmp/".time().".png", $data);
```

However all the images seem to be corrupted, although they both have the correct width height, they have zero content.

My question is how can I fix this problem hence a correct image can be made?

- I have a base64-encoded string of imagedata `iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...` where the `data:(.*)base64,` part is cut.
- The original imagedata is ok, it is directly obtained from a canvas `canvas.toDataURL()`
- PHP is a must.

Comment: I figure out during the data transfer between. the data is changed a little bit. for example ``...ggBYYgD7goE+Xxw...`` will become ``...ggBYYgD7goE Xxw...``

Comment: maybe this is the reason. But how can I fix it?

Comment: The data that you are getting in the php script, copy that image content and paste on http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter. Check if you are able to see the image

Comment: What is `$http`? Are you using a JavaScript library? Does that library take care of encoding post request payload?

Comment: ``$http`` is an angular module

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
var req = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: {data: jsonString}, 
};`

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the problem should be due to the header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which encodes the data into `url type`.

In PHP side, the data received needed to be url-decoded first.

Another solution is using `FormData` to avoid header.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', data);

var req = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    timeout: 5000,
};
$http(req)...
```